# Mysql: combine these two indexes into one?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM items 
WHERE collection_id = 10 
ORDER BY item_order ASC,id DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

Right now I have two indexes, one on collection_id,id and another on collection_id,item_order.
item_order can be null if the user has not specified an order for the items, in which case I want them sorted by id.

Is my index setup optimal, or is there a way to have one three column index that handles both sorting by id and item_order? It seem redundant to index the "collection_id" column two times..

Answer (score 3):

The optimal index for this query is `(collection_id,id,item_order)`.

MySQL will only use one index per table per query, and it looks for matching indexes by order of columns in the query.  The easiest way to determine what an index should look like for this query is by looking at the WHERE conditions followed by the ORDER BY conditions.

When in doubt, use EXPLAIN liberally and make sure it's not unnecessarily creating temporary tables or using filesort.

Comment: Sorry, owner actually shouldn't have been part of the query (updated the question). So collection_id,id,item_order?

Answer (score 1):

Using EXPLAIN before a select statement will tell you which of your indexes it is using. The official documentation is here:

[MySQL 5: Using EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)

A good tutorial is here:

[Optimizing MySQL Queries and Indexes](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

For the query above, the ideal index will be along the lines of (collection_id, item_order, id).

Indexing the same column multiple times is by no means a waste of time - so long as you don't end up with two identical indexes, or indexes which are never used.

Comment: Sorry, owner actually shouldn't have been part of the query (updated the question). I would need to index by collection_id,id in order to efficiently sort by id DESC right? (id is the autoincrement column)

Comment: If `id` is autoincrement then sorting by item_order after id (as you do in your example) is redundant - there should be no ties on an identity column.

Comment: Will: not sure I understand. users can manually specify an item order, which is what item_order is. so if item_order is not null, it should sort by that instead of id.

Comment: @makeee - should you instead have `ORDER BY item_order, id` in your query then?

Comment: No problem.  My answer is updated to reflect this - note the ordering of the columns has changed in my suggested index.

Comment: Will: I made another error in my original question. It needs to be ORDER BY item_order ASC,id DESC. Doing an EXPLAIN using your suggested index vs my original 2 index method gives me the same results ("Using where; Using filesort" and the same number of rows).

Comment: makeee: Out of interest - not that I would expect it to matter - but does changing the ORDER BY to item_order ASC, id ASC end up with the index being used?